# Foreign Key Constraints does not work with Doctrine/Symfony and SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working with Doctrine 2.4.2, Symfony 2.4 and SQLite 3.8.3.

I have two entities defined:

```
Category:
    type: entity
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    oneToMany:
        ministries:
            targetEntity: Ministry
            cascade: [persist]
            mappedBy: category
```

And

```
Ministry:
    type: entity
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    manyToOne:
        category:
            targetEntity: Category
            inversedBy: ministries
            joinColumn:
                name: category_id
                nullable: false
                onDelete: CASCADE
```

But when I delete a category, the ministry entities do not get deleted, although the constraint should cascade. What am I missing?

Do I have to configure anything to get that working?

Comment: Solution found, [redirect to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356717/symfony-doctrine2-manytomany-relationship-not-removed-specific-to-sqlite)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need to make sure that `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` is set before deleting.

Note that this is a connection setting, not a database setting.

**Addition:**
With [Symfony's event subscriber](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) it is possible to execute this command in the [preFlush](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preflush) event of Doctrine, before any writing queries are executed.

Comment: Keep in mind that even if you do this, you still can not rely on Schema Tools for foreign keys constraint additions. They're turned off permanently

Answer (score 1):

For others coming here via Google to find out why foreign keys are not enforced in doctrine.

Foreign key support in doctrine dbal SqlitePlatform has been reverted/removed as per [this comment](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/2104#issuecomment-162377952) since version 2.4.0-BETA1.

This caused for me quite some bug search in my code base simply to find out that doctrine itself removed the feature due to instability.

Answer (score 0):

Change to `cascade: ['persist', 'remove']`

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but just a workaround. It does not make sure that the database won't get into an invalid state.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key checks are disabled by default on pdo_sqlite driver. As it's mentioned [here](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html):

> Foreign key constraints are disabled by default (for backwards
> compatibility), so must be enabled separately for each database
> connection. (Note, however, that future releases of SQLite might
> change so that foreign key constraints enabled by default. Careful
> developers will not make any assumptions about whether or not foreign
> keys are enabled by default but will instead enable or disable them as
> necessary.

You should enable it before flushing via an EeventSubscriber:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\EventSubscriber\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreFlushEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;

/**
 * Class SqlitePreFlushSubscriber.
 */
final class SqlitePreFlushSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function preFlush(PreFlushEventArgs $args): void
    {
        if ('sqlite' !== \strtolower($args->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()->getName())) {
            return;
        }

        $args->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->exec('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;');
    }

    /**
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [Events::preFlush];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to always enable foreign key constraints with sqlite in Symfony 6.3 you can create the following event listener :)

```
<?php
# src/EventListener/SqlitePreFlush.php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Attribute\AsDoctrineListener;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Exception;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\SqlitePlatform;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreFlushEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;

#[AsDoctrineListener(event: Events::preFlush, priority: 500, connection: 'default')]
class SqlitePreFlush
{
    /**
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function preFlush(PreFlushEventArgs $args): void
    {
        $connection = $args->getObjectManager()->getConnection();
        if ($connection->getDatabasePlatform() instanceof SqlitePlatform) {
            $connection->executeStatement('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;');
        }
    }
}
```