# Symfony Doctrine2 manyToMany relationship not removed - Specific to SQLite

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have several classes using a Taggable trait to set up a tag system common to several doctrine entities (Project, Note, ...).

The relationship between these entities and these tags is a ManyToMany relationship that I can not make multi-directional.

My problem: When I delete a Project entity, it is removed from the **project** table, but the relationships in the **project_tag** table between this project and the tags are not deleted. Then, if I create a new Project entity, an exception is thrown.

```
An exception exists while executing 'INSERT INTO project_tag (project_id, tag_id) VALUES (?,?)' With params [2, 4]:

SQLSTATE [23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint failed: project_tag.project_id, project_tag.tag_id
```

Entities :

Tag

```
/**
 * Tag
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="tag")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\TagRepository")
 */
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_use_at", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $lastUseAt;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->lastUseAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Tag
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getLastUseAt(): \DateTime
    {
        return $this->lastUseAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $lastUseAt
     */
    public function setLastUseAt(\DateTime $lastUseAt)
    {
        $this->lastUseAt = $lastUseAt;
    }
}
```

Taggable

```
trait Taggable
{

 /**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Tag", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $tags;

/**
 * Add tag
 *
 * @param Tag $tag
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function addTag(Tag $tag)
{
    $tag->setLastUseAt(new \DateTime());
    $this->tags[] = $tag;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove tag
 *
 * @param Tag $tag
 */
public function removeTag(Tag $tag)
{
    $this->tags->removeElement($tag);
}

/**
 * Get tags
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getTags()
{
    return $this->tags;
}
}
```

Project

```
/**
 * Project
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="project")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProjectRepository")
 */
class Project
{
    use Taggable;
}
```

Note

```
class Note
{
    use Taggable;
}
```

Is this the only solution or is my annotation incomplete / incorrect?
I tried with JoinColumns, JoinTable and onDelete = "cascade" but nothing works.

In the meantime, I dodged the problem with this instruction placed before the suppresion.

```
$project->getTags()->clear();
```

Full code of the action in the controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/project/{id}/delete", name="project_delete")
 */
public function deleteAction($id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $project = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Project')->find($id);

    if(!$project) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
    }

    $project->getTags()->clear();
    $em->remove($project);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found a better solution: you can set the PRAGMA within Doctrine configuration. Like:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_sqlite'
        #server_version: '5.7'
        #charset: utf8mb4
        #default_table_options:
            #charset: utf8mb4
            #collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        options:
            'PRAGMA foreign_keys': 'ON'
```

I just tried it on my Symfony 4 application, re-created the database and tested using DB Browser for SQLite and it works as I expected.

Hope this helps

Comment: @Alex83690 I don't think so... If you're using a former version of Symfony the file where you have make the change could be another one, but the contents should be the same

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix the problem. Here's my solution working for SQLite conections.

Create an eventListener listening on the kernel.request event :

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;


use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class RequestListener
{
    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    private $doctrine;

    public function __construct(Registry $doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $this->doctrine->getConnection()->exec('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON');
    }
}
```

Service declaration

```
  app.event_listener.request_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\RequestListener
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine'
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request }
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution is specific to sqlite as you suggested in the comments below.

Comment: Maybe even better would be to use the [preFlush](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preflush) event of Doctrine (with [Symfony's event subscriber](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)). As it would prevent from executing the command on pages where no writing queries are executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have your trait `Taggable` set as the owning side of the ManyToMany relationship but your are deleting the inverse side and expecting something to happen as a result. Doctrine will only check the owning side of the relationship in order to persist any changes. See [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#important-concepts) for docs on this.

You can solve by making the `Taggable` the inverse side of each of your relationships, or by manually telling doctrine to delete the owning side.

The first solution will probably not work for you since you won't (easily) specify multiple inverse sides. (Are you sure a trait is the right way to go for this??)

The second solution is easy. In your entities like `Project` for your deleteTag($tag) function, call a delete function on the owning side (e.g., `deleteProject($project)`. You will have to create if one does not exist.

```
class Project
{
    use Taggable;

    public function deleteTag($tag)
    {
        $this->tags->removeElement($tag);

        // persist on the owning side
        $tag->deleteProject($this);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

After seeing full code, it looks like you are deleting correctly. Now you need to tell doctrine to carry that through. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472538/cascade-remove-vs-orphanremoval-true-vs-ondelete-cascade) for full details, but basically you can change your trait to this:

```
trait Taggable
{

     /**
      * @var ArrayCollection
      *
      * @ORM\ManyToMany(
      *     targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Tag", 
      *     cascade={"persist"},
      *     onDelete="CASCADE"
      * )
 */
protected $tags;

// ...
}
```

Comment: Added full code of Taggable and Tag.

I don't think we can talk about the owning side for Taggable which is nothing more than a factorization of a piece of code common to several entities. These are the entities that are the owners of the relationship, aren't they?

Then, you're right, I can't make these entities belong to the inverse sides : no several inverse sides for a single relationship.

Comment: The second solution does not seem to fit my problem. 
I can remove tags from a project; The setTags in Taggable works fine and correctly removes the relationships in the project_tag table.

It is the complete removal of a project that is problematic: The join table project_tag with a foreign key corresponding to the project are not deleted.

Comment: Thanks for posting your full code, that is helpful. It looks like you are deleting from the correct entity, so the problem lies elsewhere. I will update my answer with a suggestion to use `onDelete="CASCADE"` in your trait.

Comment: `[Creation Error] The annotation @ORM\ManyToMany declared on property AppBundle\Entity\Project::$tags does not have a property named "onDelete". Available properties: targetEntity, mappedBy, inversedBy, cascade, fetch, orphanRemoval, indexBy`

I tried onDelete="cascade" in the ORM \JoinColumn too.

Comment: I think I found the problem. Apparently this comes from sqlite which is misconfigured by Doctrine. How do I add this configuration to my connection?

foreign_keys: ON

Comment: Sorry, I don't use sqlite. You may want to start a new question.

Comment: Solution found, look the other answer. Thanks for your help.